# Unable to Response from "GetTicket" Request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am using CAS in my application. I am unable to get Ticket while running JMeter at first time.
If i run the application in Browser and Running the JMeter, Then I am able to get the ticket.

Please tell me why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Follow redirects' tick in your [HTTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).

Also ensure that you have [HTTP Cookie manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) and [HTTP Cache Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager)

Comment: Hi Jay... I have used Http cookie manager and cache manager but it is not working. Is there any other way to make it work..?